# DDD construct AggregateRoot Entity from external API, Repositories and Domain Services

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Trying to apply DDD principles to small project... I have `PlayerProfile` aggregate root, which consists of `Club` entity and collection of `Rating` value objects. Periodically I have to sync all `PlayerProfile`'s entities from external portal, parsing the raw HTML.

For now I come up with the solution to wrap the code, which renew the `PlayerProfile`'s in simple `PlayerProfileRepository`, something like this:

```
public interface IPlayerProfileRepository
{
    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<PlayerProfile>> SyncPlayersProfilesFromPortal(string sourceUrl);
    // other methods, which works with data storage
}
```

First, I don't really like the idea of mixing method, which work with data storage with the methods, which work with external resource (HTML pages) to periodically create `PlayerProfile`. For me it sounds more like `PlayerProfileFactory` responsibilities?

The actual implementation of `IPlayerProfileRepository` delegates parsing of actual pages to 3 `IPageParser`'s, which actually lives in the same layer as my repositories do. Something like this:

```
    public PlayerProfileRepository(
        IPageParser<ParseClubDto> clubPageParser,
        IPageParser<ParsePlayerProfileDto> playerProfilePageParser,
        IPageParser<ParseRatingDto> ratingPageParser)

    {
        _playerProfilePageParser = playerProfilePageParser;
        _clubPageParser = clubPageParser;
    }
```

I am not quite sure if all these `Dtos` are in fact `Dtos` as soon as they are used only from `IPageParser`'s to save intermediate data while parsing the pages. I would like to keep them closely to `IPageParser` implementations in data service layer, but not to share them in separate Dtos project and maybe named differently.

After `ParseClubDto`, `ParsePlayerProfileDto` and `ParseRatingDto` parsed, I passed it to `PlayerProfileFactory.Create` factory method, something like this:

```
var playerProfiles = new List<PlayerProfile>();

var clubs = await _clubPageParser.ParseAsync(sourceUrl);

foreach (var club in clubs)
{
    var clubPlayers = await _playerProfilePageParser.ParseAsync(club.PlayersPageUrl);

    foreach (var clubPlayer in clubPlayers)
    {
        var ratings = await _ratingPageParser.ParseAsync(clubPlayer.RatingsPageUrl);

        playerProfiles.Add(PlayerProfileFactory.Create(club, clubPlayer, ratings));
     }
}

return playerProfiles;
```

After this is done I have to perform actual syncing with existing agreggate roots in DB, which I do simple by calling `ResyncFrom(PlayerProfile profile)` on aggregate root or should it be more like separate `PlayerProfile` domain service?

In general I got a feeling that I am doing something wrong, so please any comments are welcomed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your example is a case of integration between two BCs using the anti corruption layer pattern.

I would have a port (interface in the domain) with a method contract that returns a list of player profile aggregates.

In the infrastructure layer I would have an adapter that implements the port by reading the html data from the remote portal (for example using a REST API ) and constructing the aggregates from that data.

In the application layer I would have an application service in which you inject both the port and the player profile aggregate repository that deals with the local db. The application service calls the port to construct the aggregates, and then calls the repository to store them.

I would run this application service periodically.

This would be an async integration without events, but you could implement it with events if the remote portal fires events.

Answer (score 0):

IPlayerProfileRepository interface is usually defined in the Domain and describes to the outside world how the Aggregate Root should be retrieved, usually by the Id. So the method SyncPlayersProfilesFromPortal should certainly not be a part of this interface. 
Syncing data is an infrastructure concern and can be done asynchronously in the background as already suggested in the previous answer.